# Faucet contract only permits owner to perform transactions

Tags: blockchain, solidity, smartcontracts, binance-smart-chain, bep20

All is good and work very well, but why when I need to call function requestTokens, only owner can have success on transaction while other address can't use the function because the contract cause execution revert?

ADDRESS:
0x8c08a469BDFd679CEF0729bDEa52BC688d4bDbBC

```
/\*\*
\*Submitted for verification at BscScan.com on 2023-01-30
\*/

/\*\*
// contracts/Faucet.sol
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
\*/

pragma solidity ^0.8.17;
interface IERC20 {
function transfer(address to, uint256 value) external returns (bool);
event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint256 value);
}

contract Faucet {
uint256 constant public waitTime = 1440 minutes;
bool public isFaucetActive = true;
address public owner;
IERC20 public tokenInstance;
mapping(address =\> uint256) public lastAccessTime;

constructor(address \_tokenInstance) {
require(\_tokenInstance != address(0));
tokenInstance = IERC20(\_tokenInstance);
owner = msg.sender;
}

function requestTokens(uint8 \_slice) public {
require(allowedToWithdraw(msg.sender));
require(isFaucetActive);
uint256 tokenAmount;
if(\_slice == 1) {
tokenAmount = 5 \* 10**12;
} else if(\_slice == 2) {
tokenAmount = 11 \* 10**12;
} else if(\_slice == 3) {
tokenAmount = 8 \* 10**12;
} else if(\_slice == 4) {
tokenAmount = 4 \* 10**12;
} else if(\_slice == 5) {
tokenAmount = 3 \* 10**12;
} else if(\_slice == 6) {
tokenAmount = 14 \* 10**12;
} else if(\_slice == 7) {
tokenAmount = 10 \* 10**12;
} else if(\_slice == 8) {
tokenAmount = 12 \* 10**12;
}
tokenInstance.transfer(msg.sender, tokenAmount);
lastAccessTime\[msg.sender\] = block.timestamp + waitTime;
}

function allowedToWithdraw(address \_address) public view returns (bool) {
if(lastAccessTime\[\_address\] == 0) {
return true;
} else if(block.timestamp \>= lastAccessTime\[\_address\]) {
return true;
}
return false;
}
function stopFaucet() public {
require(msg.sender == owner);
isFaucetActive = false;
}

    function activateFaucet() public {
        require(msg.sender == owner);
        isFaucetActive = true;
    }

}
```

I try all my best, like 7/8 different contract with different method

Comment: The original title was not descriptive, so I have edited it. Feel free to edit again, and please leave out "halp me" etc in the future - it's not useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To transfer the token(0xbf433345a79CF6e9270350848F88Db16d46D4f54), it should be opened. Or your faucet(0x8c08a469BDFd679CEF0729bDEa52BC688d4bDbBC) or the caller should be whitelisted on the token.
Since another address(in your failed transaction, 0x87f9F0572693258678625d29F5bbAEb02E04C14B) is not whitelisted on the token, the transaction was reverted in the modifier.

```
modifier open(address from, address to) {
    require(isOpen || _whiteList[from] || _whiteList[to], "Not Open");
    _;
}
```